# C Windows DLL Injection Notepad crashes

Tags: c, windows, dll, dll-injection

i have tryed a DLL Injection on the Programm Notepad.exe

But if i start my Injector, notepad Crashes.
Here is my Injector Code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char const Path[]="C:\\Users\\IEUser\\Desktop\\Mydll.dll";
int main(void) {

    HANDLE hWnd, hProcess, AllocAdresse, hRemoteThread;
        DWORD PID;

        hWnd = FindWindow(0,"Untitled - Notepad");
        GetWindowThreadProcessId((HWND)hWnd, &PID);

        hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PID);

        AllocAdresse = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, sizeof(Path), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
        WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)AllocAdresse, (void*)Path, sizeof(Path), 0);
        hRemoteThread=CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"),"LoadLibraryA"), AllocAdresse, 0, 0);
        WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, AllocAdresse, sizeof(Path), MEM_DECOMMIT);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 0;
}
```

And this is my Code for my DLL File:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void InjNachricht() {
    MessageBox(0, "It Works", "My DLL File", 0);
}

int WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD reason,LPVOID reserved) {
    if(reason==DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) InjNachricht, 0, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this Code in my Linux machine with MinGW:

> (Injector) i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o Injector.exe injector.c
>   (DLL-File) i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o Mydll.dll mydll.c

I also written a Function for Setting Debug Privileges:

```
void SetDebugPrivilege() {
    HANDLE hProcess=GetCurrentProcess(), hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES priv;
    LUID luid;

    OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
    LookupPrivilegeValue(0, "seDebugPrivilege", &luid);

    priv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    priv.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    priv.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &priv, 0, 0, 0);

    CloseHandle(hToken);
}
```

And if i Run my Program in my Virtual Machine:
[Notepad.exe Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjIlU.png)

Why is notepad crashing?
If i inject my dll File with the Program it works:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilna0.png)

*And please do not come with me now "Then I use the program instead of writing a separate injector" !! That does not help me any further !!*

Comment: you **must** attach debugger to notepad (target for injection process) and look exactly where and why was crash. no another way. and `MEM_DECOMMIT` is wrong flag here - must be `MEM_RELEASE` used here

Comment: it still does not work

Comment: what sense in your *still does not work* - are i advice concrete fix ? `MEM_DECOMMIT` if you not understand not related to crash at all. but it wrong because you not free memory by this (memory range still occupied). correct for free use `MEM_RELEASE`. and real what you need todo - debug notepad.

Comment: I have changed `MEM_DECOMMIT` to `MEM_RELEASE` and Notepad still crashes

Comment: look like you nothing understanding. despite I already twice say about this

Comment: …… I used a Dugger to look where Notepad crashes. That helped me in that I modified my code there. What you wrote with the MEM_DECOMMIT & MEM_RELEASE has nothing to do with what the reserved memory has released.

But thanks for saying _"look like you nothing understanding."_ @RbMm
Your comment really helped me…

Comment: yes you nothing understand. *has nothing to do with what the reserved memory has released.* was error in your code - you need use `MEM_RELEASE` for free memory instead `MEM_DECOMMIT`. of course fix this error will be no any effect to crash - really - how not free memory region can be related here ? only resource leak. for research error related to crash - use debugger

Comment: i use debugger!!

Comment: *`MEM_DECOMMIT` if you not understand not related to crash at all. but it wrong because you not free memory by this (memory range still occupied). correct for free use `MEM_RELEASE`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can use `strlen`/`wcslen` (first is for Ascii encoding, latter for Unicode encoding) instead for calculating the length of a buffer. It's more appropriate in my opinion.

Here's a properly working variant of DLL injection via remote threads which I've written as a demonstration example for you. It is a quick example so don't expect too much, extremely simplistic. You can improve it by using shell-code injection and then utilise a manual map loader or LdrLoadDll.

```
BOOLEAN InjectDll(
    HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    CHAR *DllPath
)
{
    BOOLEAN BlStatus = FALSE;
    HANDLE ThreadHandle = 0;
    PVOID LoadLibraryAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    PVOID DllMemory = 0;
    SIZE_T DllLength = strlen(DllPath);

    if (!ProcessHandle ||
        !DllPath ||
        !LoadLibraryAddress)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    DllMemory = VirtualAllocEx(ProcessHandle,
        NULL,
        DllLength,
        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
        PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (!DllMemory)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    BlStatus = WriteProcessMemory(ProcessHandle,
        DllMemory,
        DllPath,
        DllLength,
        NULL);

    if (!BlStatus)
    {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    ThreadHandle = CreateRemoteThread(ProcessHandle,
        NULL,
        0,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryAddress,
        DllMemory,
        0,
        0);

cleanup:
    if (!ThreadHandle)
    {
        if (DllMemory)
        {
            VirtualFree(DllMemory,
                NULL,
                MEM_RELEASE);
        }

        BlStatus = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        BlStatus = TRUE;
    }

    return BlStatus;
}
```

On that note, you may be interested in NtOpenProcess, NtAllocateVirtualMemory, NtWriteVirtualMemory, RtlCreateUserThread/NtCreateThreadEx and NtAdjustPrivilegesToken. As for CreateRemoteThread, it won't work with processes on other user accounts, whereas RtlCreateUserThread/NtCreateThreadEx both will (as long as you have debugging rights - SeDebugPrivilege).

As a last pointer, make sure you compile with /MT so the run-time is statically linked (especially for the DLL you're injecting). If my example code does not help you, and you still cannot fix the issue, try using a debugger to diagnose the issue. You should already have tried doing this, debuggers are there for a reason!

Comment: After taking a look at the image from the original post, I recon it's to do with the compilation of the DLL. Make sure you are statically linking the run-time for the DLL you're injecting unless the correct version is installed on the target environment, otherwise the target injected process will crash once the injected DLL loads.

Comment: notepad is still crashing. And if it hienge at the compilation of the DLL then yes the program "DLLInjector v2" in the Injecting in the Notepad process would crash synonymous or notepad would crash synonymous. This is NOT the case! And the code in my DLL works well then, but as soon as I think

Comment: Check over your DLL and the compilation configuration for it. Does the DLL inject when using an external injector instead of your own code? You should use a debugger to determine why the memory in notepad.exe is messing up.

Answer (score 2):

Its been a while since I did these things, so I may be off, but:

1. You try to map LoadLibraryA method when you run remote thread. Most of modern apps use LoadLibraryW or just LoadLibrary that will use the default value based on compiler mode.
2. You use gcc, why not use Microsoft compiler? There might be mapping issues between the compilers, that prevent you from linking the gcc generated code with (possibly) vcc compiler....

Hop it helps